# Determine the dimension of $D_0$ from the equation $\frac{∂n}{∂t}=D_0\frac{∂}{∂x}\Bigg\{n^4\frac{∂n}{∂x}\Bigg\}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

Consider the one-dimensional non-linear diffusion equation:
$$\frac{∂n}{∂t}=D_0\frac{∂}{∂x}\Bigg\{n^4\frac{∂n}{∂x}\Bigg\}$$

where $t$ is time, $x$ is the spatial coordinate, $D_0$ is the coefficient of diffusion and $n$ is the concentration with $[n] = ML^{−3}.$

- Determine the dimension of $D_0$.
- Bring the equation into non-dimensional form, if it is known that there is a characteristic value of the concentration $n_0$, and a characteristic length scale $L.$

I've been working on these 2 questions for the last couple of hours with no luck. So any help for both answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you think the units of $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}$ are?

Comment: Well in non-dimensional form, the units would be: $ML^{-3}T^{-1}$. Ive tried many things which havent worked. Could you help me get to the answer? @Matt

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:

$T^{-1}ML^{-3}=[D_0]L^{-1}M^4L^{-12}ML^{-3}L^{-1}$

$T^{-1}ML^{-3}LM^{-4}L^{12}M^{-1}L^3L=[D_0]$

$T^{-1}M^{-4}L^{14}=[D_0]$

For the second:

$\bar D_0=D_0\dfrac{n_0^4}{L^2}$ with $\bar n=n/n_0$ and $\bar x=x/L$

But not completely non-dimensional:

$[\bar D_0]=T^{-1}$